How to manipulate a session from Livewire globally across the entire project (classic controller included)?
I'm having an issue with Livewire and session data seems to be automatically cached by Livewire:

I have a Livewire component "1" that allows you to select a store from a list,

Once a store is selected, a Livewire function is triggered via wire:click to save the selected store session and a withdrawal hour in session,

Another Livewire component "2" allows you to display the selected store and the withdrawal hour,

This Livewire component "2" at the time of mount(), checks if the withdrawal hour is not less than the current one, if yes we modify the withdrawal hour by modifying the session via session()->put().
-> It is at this step that the problem appears, the session is indeed modified when the component is displayed and the modified withdrawal hour appears. On the other hand, if I refresh the page or change pages, the saved session is always the old one. Likewise if I display the session in a classic controller, I have the old value. I am forced to F5 the page several times for the new value to be definitively saved.


Has anyone encountered this issue before?
Thanks!
I tried to delete the session instead of modifying it from the Livewire function but I see that it is not deleted. If I change pages, the old value reappears. It seems that the session is deleted locally at the time the code is executed but not globally.

It would help if you shared sample code.
